# I am trying to make a platform around the bottom of the screen but it keeps giving me an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a problem when I made my code and This is the error it shows

> ```
> platforms_list.append[pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White)]
> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
> ```

I don't get what it means by subscriptable. I have a circle player that can jump move and can go around but falls off his platform because there is no bottom platform and I don't no how to make it

```
import math
import os
import sys
# It is importing everything
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class Platform:
    def __init__(self, size, x, y, color):
        #size is a list, this means it has width and height
        self.size = size
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color

    # This is what the platform class has and what it does
    def draw(self):
        display = pygame.display.get_surface()
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.color, (int(self.x), int(self.y), self.size[0], self.size[1]))

    # This is def draw function is showing that how I want my Platform to look like
    def do(self):
        self.draw()


# The def do function is running def draw function

class Player:
    def __init__(self, velocity, maxJumpRange, x, y, size):
        self.falling = True
        self.jumpCounter = 0
        self.xVelocity = 0
        self.y = y
        self.x = x
        self.jumping = False
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.maxJumpRange = maxJumpRange
        self.jump_offset = 0
        self.size = size
        self.TouchedGround = False

    # The player class is making how the Player is going to look and what are his limits

    def keys(self):
        k = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        # The def keys(self): is creating a variable for pygame.key.get_pressed() and underneath is a function to make the player move around
        if k[K_LEFT]:
            self.xVelocity = -self.velocity
        elif k[K_RIGHT]:
            self.xVelocity = self.velocity
        else:
            self.xVelocity = 0

        if (k[K_SPACE] or k[K_UP]) and not self.jumping and self.TouchedGround:
            self.jumping = True
            self.jumpCounter = 0
            self.TouchedGround = False


    # The if k[K_Space] or k[K_UP] is making sure the player has a jump limit and can't continue jumping forever.
    def move(self):
        self.x += self.xVelocity
        # if the player is jumping, change y value
        if self.jumping:
            self.y -= self.velocity
            self.jumpCounter += 1
            if self.jumpCounter == self.maxJumpRange:
                self.jumping = False
                self.falling = True
        elif self.falling:
            self.y += self.velocity
            self.jumpCounter -= 1


    def draw(self):
        display = pygame.display.get_surface()
        pygame.draw.circle(display, White, (int(self.x), int(self.y)), self.size)

    def do(self):
        self.keys()
        self.move()
        self.draw()


# This Function is doing all of the Functions self.keys(), self.move(), self.draw()

def events():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



#window size

w = 576
h = 516

# The above is showing the width the height and Area
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "50,50"
# the above is showing what the graphics are

#player
p = Player(1, 100, 290, 250, 30)


#start pygame
pygame.init()
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
DS = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))  # This is what the display size is
pygame.display.set_caption("Try to get point B")



#variables
FPS = 120
Black = (0, 0, 0, 255)
White = (255, 255, 255, 255)
Red = (255, 0, 0)


# Bkgd stands for background
bkgd = pygame.Surface((w,h))  # didnt have the image so i made it blue
bkgd.fill((0,0,255))



#platforms
pl = Platform([290,20], 250, 350, White)
#this is a list that holds all the platforms
platforms_list = [pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White)]
platforms_list.append[pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White)]
#this is how much to scroll the background by
background_scroll = 0


# What the while true loop is doing is to make sure that the background moves while the player moves
while True:
    events()

    #blit the background, since the image is same size as window blit twice so when scrolls, you dont have blackness
    DS.blit(bkgd, (-background_scroll, 0))
    DS.blit(bkgd, (w-background_scroll, 0))

    #check for x button clicked
    events()

    #update the player
    p.do()

    #update platforms and check for collision with player
    platform_color = Red
    for platform in platforms_list:
        platform.color = platform_color
        if p.jumping == 0:
            platform.color = White
        platform.do()
        #if bottom of player is in the platform, move the player on top of the platform
        if p.y + p.size > platform.y and p.y + p.size < platform.y + platform.size[1]:
            if p.x > platform.x and p.x < platform.x + platform.size[0]:
                p.y = platform.y - p.size
                p.TouchedGround = True

    #if the player reaches the side of the screen, move the background and platforms to make it look like it is moving
    if p.x + p.size >= w:
        p.x = w - p.size
        background_scroll += 1
        for platform in platforms_list:
            platform.x -= 1
        if background_scroll == w:
            background_scroll = 0
    #same but for the left
    if p.x - p.size <= 0:
        p.x = 0 + p.size
        background_scroll -= 1
        for platform in platforms_list:
            platform.x += 1
        if background_scroll == 0:
            background_scroll = w

    #update screen
    pygame.display.update()
    Clock.tick(FPS)
    DS.fill(Black)
```

`platforms_list.append[pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White)]` this is the code that I added but it keeps giving me the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think append needs to be `.append()` not `[]`.

Try this:

```py
platforms_list.append(pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White))
```

Comment: It didn't work instead it gives this error   
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mitta/PycharmProjects/untitled1/Scrolling2.0.py", line 133, in <module>
    platforms_list.append(pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White))
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: I see the problem. Try ```platforms_list.append([pl,Platform([200,20], 100, 450, White), Platform([200,20], 400, 250, White)])```

Comment: It works sorry took so long to respond laptop died and had to get a new one. Thanks for the help.